# Checklist-model doesn't works angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, .net, angularjs, checklist-model

I have some problem with my code impementing checklist-model.
My checkbox is not filling my model

**Markup**

```
<label>Service Lead *</label>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button title="This is a required field" ng-style="{'border-color': Style.Color}" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width:65%">
           {{SLDefaultText}}
            <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-click="SetSLText(sl)" ng-repeat="sl in ServiceLeads">
            <a href="#"><input type="checkbox" checklist-model="newProject.listOfSL" checklist-value="sl" />{{sl.FullName}}</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.newProject = { ProjectId: 0, ProjectName: '', ProjectDescription: '' };

  $scope.init = function () {
    $scope.GetPorjects();
};

$scope.GetPorjects = function () {
    var responsePromise = $http.get("http://localhost:21294/api/Project");

    responsePromise.success(function (listOfProjects) {
        $('#tblProjects').hide();
        $scope.newProject = {
            DeliveryManager: {},
            listOfSL:[],
            listOfTL:[],
            listOfCL:[]
        };
        $scope.projects = listOfProjects;
        //$scope.listOfUsers = listOfProjects.$scope.listOfUsers;
        $('#tblProjects').show('slow');
    });
    responsePromise.error(function (data) {
        toastr.error("Error calling service: ");
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't see where `ServiceLeads` is defined. Could you please create a stripped down to minimal example of your issue?

Comment: I found the solution, my bad I forget pass the parameter ["checklist-model"] in my controller.